# Guava eventbus memory limit

Tags: java, guava, event-bus

I implemented a singleton `EventBus` with one subscriber. My application has many producer (any request can be a producer).

```
@Bean
public EventBus eventBus() {
    EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();
    eventBus.register(new MyEventHandler());
    return eventBus;
}
```

I could not find how to set a limit on number of events for the `EventBus` (how to set a memory limit for the `EventBus`) and also what happens if the number of produced events is greater than `EventBus` capacity.

I would like `EventBus` to throw an exception to log the failure.

Answer (score 0):

No need to set a memory limit. It’s safe, because `EventBus` works **stateless**.

In a single thread, the `EventBus` cleans up the event-queue every time once `EventBus.post()` completes, so it’s safe in a single thread.

In multiple-thread, `EventBus` uses independent event-queue for each thread.

Comment: So basically the queue limit is the server memory limit? it tries to fill the queue until no memory left? And by multi-thread EventBus are you talking about AsyncEventBus?